# If a number is allowed to appear twice (but not three times) how many different combinations are possible?

Tags: probability

The Honest Lock Company plans to introduce what it refers to as the "true combination lock." The lock will open if the correct set of three numbers from 0 to 39 is entered in any order.

Comment: Stefan Waner, Steven R. Costenoble, "Finite Mathematics," Page 440.. Is this a homework problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

By construction: Consider all the ways to choose 3 distinct values from 40 possible values and then consider the permutations of choosing 2 distinct values from 40 as this would be how I'd compute the answer.

By exclusion, from User58220's idea : Consider all the possible 3 number configurations without restriction and then remove the ones where all 3 are the same.  If the lock went from 0 to 9 and had 3 digits, the arithmetic would be $10^3-10=990$ as there are 1,000 3 digit possibilities and there are 10 where all the digits are the same.

Comment: Hint II:  Consider how to pick three numbers with *no* restrictions and then how to pick three *identical* numbers.  Subtract